# Django: DB queries count optimization

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-orm

I have models (one user can has multiple employees):

```
from django.db import models


class User(models.Model):
    username = ...
    first_name = ...
    last_name = ...


class OrgUnit(models.Model):
    name = ....
    address = ...


class Employee(models.Model):
    personnel_no = ...
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='employees'...)
    orgunit = models.ForeignKey(OrgUnit, ...)
```

Serializers and views:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    orgunit = serializers.CharField(source='orgunit.name') <==== one orgunit - one query to DB

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'


class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    employees = EmployeeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


class UsersViewSet(ViewSet):
   
    def me(self, request):
        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

When serializing orgunit.name per one orgunit one query to DB is being performed. How to avoid this? How to prefetch `employees` related_name and its `orgunits`?

Comment: Can you explain your questions properly? Like do you want to get all the related data (of foreign keys) when you call objects from OrgUnit or Employee model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can use [**`Prefetch`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) and  [**`prefetch_related_objects`**..[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related-objects) to fetch all related employees with `orgunit` selected as well:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch, prefetch_related_objects


class UsersViewSet(ViewSet):
    def me(self, request):
        prefetch_related_objects(
            [request.user], 
            Prefetch(
                "employees", 
                queryset=Employee.objects.select_related("orgunit"),
            ),
        )

        serializer = CustomUserSerializer(request.user)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```